# HM-10 connect to long UUID

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I have two HRM device one of them I am able to connect to it by setting the AT+UUID0x180D and AT+CHAR0x2A37 which they are the default UUIDs to subscribe to the HR values, and I follow the commands with AT+CO1 command and I start receiving the HR values

I have another HRM device which uses an unknown service which is 32 digits of a hex UUID totally different than the default HRM UUIDs,

AT+CHAR commands accepts till 0xFFFE and I need to set a full address, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Try it using the hex digits 5 to 8 of the full UUID.

Answer (score 0):

I came to knew that HM-10 does not support such UUIDs and I had to move to esp32 which has all I need